# 'Merging Cells' in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an excel sheet that has a number of entities that are defined by their 'Job Number'. However, I need multiple rows per job meaning that the column ends up having duplicates, such as in

[image: this picture]

Is there a way to combine each group of identical job number so that they are a 'single' row?  is what the preferred layout is.

[image: Preferred Layout]

Note: Each job is guaranteed to be 3 rows, so it will always follow the same pattern. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use VBA to merge the cells and center the contents.

Comment: Well the reason I want to use a table for this is so that the formulas in other columns can be flood filled through out. I'm not 100% sure how I would go about setting that up in VBA

Comment: You cannot merge cells in a *Table*. Does it have to be one?

Comment: Could you present the desired view in a separate tabular pivot table?

Comment: Ideally it would be a table, since there are calculated columns throughout, and given that just adding a 'row' to the end wouldn't extend the formula, it makes it difficult for the users of the excel sheet to work with it. I am essentially trying to simplify the sheet so that they can't make as many mistakes, and to reduce data redundancy. @MarkFitzgerald there is no way for this to be a pivot table. I have experimented with the use of them, but it just wouldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

`Sub Test()
TitleRow = 1 'if title contain more than one row, change the value 1 to the actual number of rows
i = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do
Set StartCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (TitleRow + 3 * i + 1))
Set EndCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (TitleRow + 3 * i + 3))
With ActiveSheet.Range(StartCell, EndCell)
.Merge
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
i = i + 1
Loop Until Range("A" & (TitleRow + 3 * i) + 1) = ""
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It can be done easily using macro or VBA, Edit below code in VBA as per your requirement.

Range("A1:A3").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Comment: `Range("A1:A3")` is defining the range as an absolute. Since I would need to do it for every single group of rows, how would I go about that?